# Using surfaceView with xml

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am refering to [Using MySurfaceView with main.xml (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8149225/1393006), with the code "textView1.setText("set");" inside the onCreate method there will be an error ( tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);  - declare is working fine). How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class For12junonly2Activity extends Activity {


TextView tv1;
EditText et1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);     
    tv1.setText("Hi");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("prob",String.valueOf(e));
    }
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    float sss = surf.getX();
    Log.d("float create",String.valueOf(sss));
}

}

 class surf extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
...... from https://stackoverflow.com/q/8149225/1393006




public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{   
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, event.getX() - (myBitmap.getWidth() / 2), event.getY() - (myBitmap.getHeight() / 2), null);
    canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 10, paint);
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    Log.d("onTouch","X: "+event.getX()+" , Y: "+event.getY());
    x = event.getX();
    return true;
}
}
```

code from xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="tv1" />

<te.de11.surf
    android:id="@+id/surfaceview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />
```

error message from log cat

```
D/dalvikvm(443): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(443): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
D/prob(363): java.lang.NullPointerException
D/float create(363): 0.0
I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed te.de11/.For12junonly2Activity: +1s29ms
D/dalvikvm(127): GC_EXPLICIT freed 66K, 52% free 2855K/5895K, external 4998K/6087K, paused 44ms
```

Comment: W/dalvikvm(403): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560), does this kind of error message help?

Comment: Not really, could you enclose to code in a try-catch block, and print the stack trace in the catch block and post that?

Comment: I got null pointer exception, but why is it so? I did all the declaration that work normally on my another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a reference to the TextView in your XML before setting that XML as the view for your activity. As your Activity doesn't have any view right now, any findViewById() call will result in a NullPointerException. To fix it, simply call `setContentView()` before referencing any of the widgets used in the XML. It is usually called directly after the `super()` call.

Comment: what you are saying is exactly what I did before posting the question, however it is not working.

Comment: In that case, please provide the entire LogCat stack trace for the NullPointerException, along with the related code.

Comment: It is working now. I remove some part of the code/comments in hurry cause you seems like impatiently waiting, so I have no idea what I changed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry if I gave that impression :P It would be nice if you could add the final solution as an answer and accept for the reference of future visitors.

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken. It is still not resolved. I set the text in xml and I thought it works. With the try and catch, it is able to stop the program from crashing but it still didnt set the text.

Comment: Could you post the exact code you are using to get a reference to the TextView, as well as the one you are using to set the text?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12455/discussion-between-amber-and-raghav-sood)